# How To Use WHERE clause with LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my query:

```
SELECT 2016step2a1.id_step2a1, 2016step2a1.camperLast, 2016step2a1.camperFirst, 
        2016step2a1.camperGender, 2016step2a1.camperAge, 2016step2a1.guardName, 
        2016step2a1.guardCellphone, 2016step2a1.camperAddress, 2016step2a1.camperApartment, 
        2016step2a1.camperCity, 2016step2a1.camperState, 2016step2a1.camperZip, 
        2016step2a1.guardEmail, 2016step2a1.camperDiag, 2016step2a6.shirtT
FROM 2016step2a1
LEFT JOIN 2016step2a6 ON 2016step2a1.user_id = 2016step2a6.user_id
LEFT JOIN 2016step2a4 ON 2016step2a1.user_id = 2016step2a4.user_id
LEFT JOIN 2016step2a5 ON 2016step2a1.user_id = 2016step2a5.user_id
WHERE 2016step2a1.whichCamp = CampIAM
```

Can someone please help me figure out why this wont run?

Comment: Because `CampIAM` needs to be quoted?

Comment: won't run **HOW**? no results? syntax error? wrong results?

Comment: You should explain, what problem you have and what you are trying, e.g. what `CampIAM` is. Could be a literal string or some field of one of the referenced tables. Read [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: If you have a table called 2016step2a1 there's a likelihood that something's gone very wrong somewhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your where clause to properly quote the right hand side value.

`WHERE 2016step2a1.whichCamp = 'CampIAM'`